# How to indicate a clickable row in a table

Tags: android, material-design, usability

I have a list on my app on which some rows are clickable and some rows aren't. My problem is how to make it clear to the user that some of the rows are clickable.

On iOS there's the right-pointing caret that serves to this purpose:

[image]

But this is something discouraged by the android guide (https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html).

So, what's the best practice to indicate the clickable rows on Android, following the Material Design paradigm?